# Laravel 5.4: REST Controller 'Edit' view not displaying existing data, and throwing 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException' on update

Tags: php, laravel, http

The 'edit' view for my blog posts is accessed via the index view which looks like this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('stylesheet')
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend.css') }}">
@endsection

@section('content')
  <h1 class="backend_title">Viewing All Posts</h1>
  <hr class="divider">
  @foreach( $posts as $post )

    <div class="backend_index-listing">
      <label class="backend_index-listing_title">{{ $post->title }}</label>
      <div class="backend_route-group">
        <a class="backend_route" href="{{ route('posts.edit', $post) }}">Edit</a>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.destroy', $post) }}">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="backend_route">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
          {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  @endforeach
@endsection
```

The edit view is as follows:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('stylesheet')
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/backend.css') }}">
@endsection

@section('content')
  <h1 class="backend_title">Edit Post</h1>
  <hr class="divider">
  <form class="backend_form" method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.update', $posts) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="backend_form-group">
      <label for="title" class="backend_label">Title</label>
      <input id="title" name="title" class="backend_input" required value="{{ $posts->title }}">
    </div>
    <div class="backend_form-group">
      <label for="slug" class="backend_label">Slug</label>
      <input id="slug" name="slug" class="backend_input" required value="{{ $posts->slug }}">
    </div>
    <div class="backend_form-group">
      <label for="body" class="backend_label">{{ $posts->body }}</label>
      <textarea id="body" name="body" class="backend_textarea" rows="40" required>{{ $posts->body }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <input class="backend_submit" type="submit" value="Update">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
  </form>
@endsection
```

Here's the edit function in the `PostsController`.

```
public function edit(Posts $posts)
{
    return view('posts.edit')->withPosts($posts);
}
```

And the update function.

```
public function update(Request $request, Posts $posts)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
    'title' => 'required|255',
    'slug' => 'required|255',
    'body' => 'required'
    ));

    $posts->title = $request->title;
    $posts->slug = $request->slug;
    $posts->body = $request->body;

    $posts->save();

    return redirect('posts');
}
```

I have a test post that I created through my create form, so create and store are working. It shows up just fine on index with the information I want. But when I click the edit button, it takes me to an empty edit view, and if I fill the fields and hit the update button, I get the 'MethodNotAllowed' exception as in the title.

Comment: can you show your update  route too

Comment: There is no explicit update route. I used Laravel's resource route syntax and declared `Route::resource('posts', PostsController)`. It shows up in `php artisan route:list` with a URI of `posts/{post}`

Comment: Because your navigating edit url using anchor tag . anchor tag is not post method so it's throwing method error . instead of anchor try to submit the form with post method or keep anchor and change your route to get method  . @user968270

Comment: in resource route edit method is already created with get method in controller with id parameter but you are passing array to in it

Comment: The edit method was not created with an ID parameter, though I know it would have been in the past and has been in two previous Laravel apps I built. As you can see above, the 'edit' function in the Resource controller was built with the parameters `(Posts $posts)`, and this is how it was made by the artisan command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
href="{{ route('posts.edit', $post) }}"
```

on

```
href="{{ route('posts.edit', ['post' => $post]) }}"
```

Hope it help you to find right solution :)